# Sharing files in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

my post-commit build process in Jenkins prepares several files that are very useful in everyday development. Currently we zip necessary files, copy to a director that is simply shared resource.

I'm looking for some kind of a plugin that would allow me to point a directory for publishing and present its content (something like workspace view in defined job).

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Isn't that something you could do with the build artifacts? I.e. specify everything you want to publish as an artifact.

Comment: True, I can prepare artifact but there's still a target directory to drop it and no way to publish it (make available via jenkins web page).

Comment: The artifacts are available through the jenkins website, aren't they?

Comment: True, just realized :) Thx for hint! Are there any other ways ? Like a button in main JOB page ?

Comment: What concerns artifacts, its manual says that "You can only archive files that are located in your workspace", in my case I'd like to share files that are not in workspace. Haven't tested yet...

Comment: You can add arbitrary links to the side bar with [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin). Would that fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solve this problem with jenkins default direcotry JENKINS_HOME\userContetn (files available from jenkins web page) and mentioned here side-bar-plugin. I created needed symbolic links in userContents and then added applicable links to mail window. Works great. Thx for hints!

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to serve files from the jenkins server without authenticating?